# How to do automatic stock update upon entering purchase & sales

Tags: insert-update, stock, auto-update

Well, I'm using `Access` as DB containing five tables viz. `Vendors, PurOrder, Customers, SalesOrder, Stock.`

```
Vendors: VendorID(PK), Name, Contact, Phone, Address.

PurOrder: POID(PK), Items, Quantity, Rate, Total

Customers: CustID(PK), Name, Phone, Address

SalesOrder: SOID(PK), Items, Quantity, Rate, Total

Stock: SItemID(PK), Items, Quantity, Rate, Total
```

I'm using the Database Wizard in `VB.NET Express`. I do not need to code for that.
I click on Data Sourses > add the Database > Drag that to my Purchase and Sales form and that automaticaly creates the ADD, DELETE, & SAVE as well as Navigation buttons as toolstrip. and furthermore I drag the Purchase order table (for example) to the form in Datagrid mode and that's it! Now, I can SAVE, DELETE, & ADD records to my database as Purchases.

Well I am able to enter and save/update purchase and sales vouchers and retrieve the reports Customer/Vendor ID-wise and print that.

The only problem I have is that I don't know what to do in order to automatically update the sock quantity when purchase or sale is made.

Thanks in advance.